# PHP get directory of file including a script

Tags: php

File `/dir/dir_a/a.php` includes file `/dir/dir_b/b.php` which is located in a different directory.

If I try to get the parent directory with `dirname(__FILE__)` or `getcwd()` inside `b.php` the result is always `dir_b`, with no surprise.

Is there a way to get the name of `dir_a` with code inside `b.php`?

Comment: Use absolut paths

Comment: Look at backtrace http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php. It will return an array with the call stack. The overhead of working with it might be high. Alternatively you could also just set/pass a parameter to know where it came from.

Comment: [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) doesn't help. It returns the current directory of the interpreter and there is no requirement or restriction about it. It can return any directory on the disk, not related in any way with the file where you call it.

Comment: *"Is there a way to get the name of `dir_a` with code inside `b.php`?"* -- if `a.php` includes `b.php`, this is a sign you are doing something wrong. What if `b.php` is not included by `a.php` but by `c.php`? What if it is not included at all but invoked as a standalone script? If `b.php` needs some information from `a.php` then `a.php` must pass this information to it. Also `b.php` must be prepared to work correctly when the information is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's perfectly normal, as [magic constants](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) for files and directories always refer to the script they are in.

For what you want, you just need to use :

```
// in b.php /dir/dir_a is
$dir_a_path = __DIR__ . '/../dir_a';
// in a.php, you can
include(__DIR__ . '/../dir_b/b.php');
```

The / will work everywhere (even windows) since we are using a full path.
**DIR** is the magic constant for the directory full path where the script using it is.